# Help understanding non-standard notation ($H_{ij}=I_iJ_j$ where $I_i$ and $J_j$ are intervals)

Tags: notation, riemann-integration, set-partition

[image]

In particular, what does 
$$H_{ij}=I_iJ_j$$
mean? It says that $H_{ij}$ are a partition of $[a,b]$. But it also says that both $I_i$ and $J_j$ are partitions of $[a,b]$.

So, what does the author mean by this notation, and hy are $H_{ij}$ a partition of $[a,b]$. Is it the intersection of the two intervals $I_i$ and $J_j$?. Like a product of indicator variables maybe?

EDIT:

Please someone answer. Im guessing its a simple thing for a mathematician, but I have never seen this notation.

Comment: Maybe the union of the partitions?

Comment: if it is a union, would it still hold that it is a partition? There is no restriction $I_i\cap J_j= \emptyset$. Than their unions could have non empty intersections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It likely means $H_{ij} = I_i \cap J_j$, so that $\{H_{ij}\}$ becomes a partition that is a refinement of both $\{I_i\}$ and $\{J_j\}$. This is similar to the notation $AB$ for the intersection of events $A \cap B$ in probability.

Side note: the author's use of "$\epsilon$" for both an actual epsilon as well as the inclusion "$\in$" is giving me conniptions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This would make sense, yes. Might I also ask you, why the last statement in the image ($\sum_{i,j}(k_j+y_i)|H_{ij}|$ is an lower bound on $\int k$) implies that $$\int k- \sum_{i=0}^ry_i|I_i| \ge \sum_{j=0}^sk_j|J_j|$$. I will accept your answer in either case.

Comment: @LeastSquaresWonderer Show that $\sum_{i,j} k_j |H_{ij}| = \sum_j k_j|J_j|$ and $\sum_{i,j} y_i |H_{i,j}| = \sum_i y_i |I_i|$.

Comment: I have been studying for the past 13 hours... I need a break, as this was pretty obvious. Thank you very much!